# Set data-icon value with parent class

Tags: jquery, icons, attr, inheritance

I'm struggling to get my head around this - I'm new to Jquery.  I'm trying to give each element an icon based on its parent's class - for use in a portfolio filter (i.e. web projects have web icon, graphics projects have graphic icon, and so on).

This is what I have done so far (simplified):

```
<!-- Project Thumbnails -->

<ul id="thumbs">
    <li class="web">
        <a name="div1"><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon=""></span><img src="img/project1.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="graphics">
        <a name="div2"><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon=""></span><img src="img/project2.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="photography">
        <a name="div3"><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon=""></span><img src="img/project3.png" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the Jquery:

```
// Determine span class by parent class
$("#thumbs li a").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $thisparent = $(this).parent();
    $span = $(this).children('span');

    $span.addClass($thisparent.attr('class'));  
});
```

So, I am able to give each span a class, inherited from its parent - allowing me to style each project category differently.  But how do I set the data-icon value?

I'm using [Icomoon](http://icomoon.io/) to embed my icons, so obviously the data-icon value will be something like `&#x0037;` - so each filter category (web, photography, graphics) will have to be linked to a specific data-icon value somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `.attr('data-icon','whatever')`?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe?  If it worked in a similar way to css where I could just give each icon a class and link it that way, it would be easier, but the icons all have weird names like `&#x0037;` etc.  Confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#thumbs li a span").each(function(){
    var cls=$(this).closest('li').attr('class');
    $(this).attr({'class':cls, 'data-icon':cls });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iyagit/1/edit). See the source by inspector tool of the browser.

**Result:**

```
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="web" class="web"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="graphics" class="graphics"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="photography" class="photography"></span>
```

**Update:** Also you can keep your icon's name in a predefined object and then use it, i.e.

```
var icons={'web':'globe', 'graphics':'picture','photography':'photo'};
$("#thumbs li a span").each(function(){
    var cls=$(this).closest('li').attr('class');
    $(this).attr({'class':cls, 'data-icon':icons[cls] });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iyagit/2/edit).See the source by inspector tool of the browser.

**Result:**

```
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="globe" class="web"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="picture" class="graphics"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="photo" class="photography"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I can't see how this would work though, since the icons embedded in the font all have weird names like `&#x0037;`.  Can you change the names of the icons?

Comment: @Salmonface, Yes you can use/change `icons={'web':'&#x0037;'}`

Comment: Ahhh!  Superb!  Thanks a million.  I've just noticed, you've written 'globe' and 'picture' etc. in place of where the data-icon value would be.  That makes perfect sense.  Sorry for not seeing that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#thumbs li a").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisparent = $(this).parent();
    var $span = $thisparent.find('span');

    $span.addClass($thisparent.attr('class'));  
    $span.data('icon',$thisparent.attr('class')); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the icons aren't named by class, they all have individual names like `&#x0037;` so how would this work?  Sorry, I'm a n00b.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
// Determine span class by parent class
$("#thumbs li a").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $thisparent = $(this).parent();
    $span = $(this).children('span');

    $span.addClass($thisparent.attr('class')); 
    $span.data('icon',$thisparent.attr('class')); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, see my comment above.